# select options to apply to different users

Tags: php, mysqli

`dropmenu` is `<select name="dropbox">` with 3 options - admin, activate, delete. The below snippet of code shows if the activate `<option>` is selected and submitted by the `submit` button then echo etc. I have a `<select name="dropbox">` on every row for each user. My code only works if i change the last drop box.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
      if(isset($_POST['dropmenu']) && $_POST['dropmenu'] == 'activate')  
      {
      echo 'is activated';
      }
      else{
        echo 'fail';
      }
 }
```

Is there a way i can use foreach drop box with a value selected?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is to connect the name of the select element with user id like

```
<select name="dropbox_[userId]">
```

In this case you simply know how to build an input name for checking it's value in `$_POST` table.

If you don't interate by users on submit code then you can use a regular expression to get an inforamtion abut user connected with element.

Comment: so then each dropbox has a unique name. Then do i add them to a variable? `<select name="'.$userid."> ?

Comment: Which variable do you mean?

Comment: what im trying to acheive is a list of users which arent activated. I then select the users i want to activate by selecting the option activate in the drop box for each user then when i press submit i want a result for each user i selected the action activate.

Comment: No, there is no need to add this names intu variable $userid. You can use a template for name like '<select name="dropbox_'.$userid.'">'.

Comment: yes but then how do i get the option selected for each dropbox `foreach $userid == activate echo $username activated

Comment: Every select for every user will apear in $_POST array like for example $_POST['dropbox_1'], $_POST['dropbox_2'], $_POST['dropbox_3']. If you know the template of this name (every name started by 'dropbox_') then you know the user id an the selected value for it.

Comment: the list of users will grow which means the dropbox amount will grow i want it to loop through each user to check if the result is activate and for each user with option activate echo the result

Comment: So if you iterate by users then you can simply check values for known users id like $_POST['dropbox_'.$userid]

Comment: I've done exactly that but getting an undefined id variable